# How can I show a redux-form warning as a result of async-validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

[Redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/) supports [validation errors and warnings](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncvalidation/).

An error displays a message and prevents the form from being submitted, where as a warning just shows a message.

[Redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/) also support [async validation](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/asyncvalidation/).

I made the mistake of assuming that async validation errors and warnings would be supported, but this isn't the case.

Unfortunately [warnings are not officially possible with async validation](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2827).

It would currently take considerable effort to move away from using [redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/), so I'm trying to find a workaround that will suffice.

One solution would be to manually add warnings to a form. If that's possible then the async validation could be performed mostly as normal, but with setting the warnings at the end, rather than providing the expected error object.

But I've looked at the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a way to manually add warnings, or errors for that matter.

You pass validation functions either to a [specific field](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/), or [the form as a whole](https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncvalidation/), and these validator functions are called as needed by [redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/).

So it appears that errors and warnings can't be set directly but maybe we can manually trigger re-validation of a specific field?

No, apparently [this is also not currently possible](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3466).

So to summarize:

- Async validation warnings aren't possible.
- Manually setting warnings for a form isn't possible.
- Manually triggering synchronous validation of a field isn't possible.

Any suggestions, insight, or corrections are very welcome.
I'll be very happy if I'm wrong on any of those summary points!

If I can't find a solution then I'll look for an alternative library, and I'll start the arduous task of moving away from [redux-forms](https://redux-form.com/).

This has certainly been a good reminder about the folly of assumptions on my part.

Comment: One of the commenters, terolepisto, in the [GitHub](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2827#issuecomment-360769286) issue about this has provided a suggestion for a workaround. It's simply to by-pass redux-forms completely and pass extra props to the controls to handle the async warning. If terolepisto hasn't added this as an answer in a few days then I'll self answer with a link providing credit.

Comment: Can't you simply append the warnings to the reducer using `reducer.plugin()`? I haven't used it, but I think it makes sense for such a situation.

Comment: I don't think that qualifies as "simply", but yeah that certainly looks to be an option. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I think you're right, but probably a bit less work than "If I can't find a solution then I'll look for an alternative library, and I'll start the arduous task of moving away from redux-forms." ;-)

Comment: Yep, you're right there.

Comment: @AndyJ no answers posted, do you want to post the answer mentioned in your first comment?

Answer (score 6):

I went with Dennie's recommendation and use `reducer.plugin()` in my root reducer to listen for redux form's async validation completion action `@@redux-form/STOP_ASYNC_VALIDATION` and (rightly or wrongly) change it from an error to a warning by injecting the `action.payload` into `syncWarnings`. Redux-form then passes this as a  `meta.warning` prop to the field.

Reducer code:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

...

const errorToWarning = (state, action) => {
  /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars, no-case-declarations */
  switch (action.type) {
    case "@@redux-form/STOP_ASYNC_VALIDATION":
      const { asyncErrors, ...noErrors } = state;
      const syncWarnings = action.payload || undefined;
      return { ...noErrors, syncWarnings };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    FirstForm: errorToWarning,
    AnotherForm: errorToWarning
  }),
  // other reducers
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Component:

```
const MyTextField = ({ meta: { touched, error, warning }, ...props }) => {
  let cssClass = "";
  let errorText = "";

  if (touched) {
    cssClass = warning ? "warning" : cssClass;
    cssClass = error ? "error" : cssClass;

    errorText = warning || errorText;
    errorText = error || errorText;
  }

  return (
    <TextField
      className={cssClass}
      hintText={props.hintText || ""}
      {...props}
      errorText={errorText}
      warning={warning}
    />
  );
};
```

I am using Material UI (that's where `TextField` comes from, not shown in imports).

See [redux-form docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/) for more info on `reducer.plugin()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Worked "out of the box" in our app, too bad that it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

The async validation callback for a form passes in `dispatch` as a second argument. That would allow you to trigger an action to add a custom warning to the global Redux state object. If you don't throw any errors then the form will still be considered valid.

For example, if you wanted to warn the user about some given input but wanted to allow them to submit their data anyway, you could call `dispatch` with some custom action that adds a warning to a global `warnings` array.

```
import { addWarning } from '../actions/warning';
import { db } from '../db';

export const asyncValidate = async (values, dispatch) => {
  const someNonUniqueValueAlreadyExists = await db.findOne('someProperty', values.someValue);

  if (someNonUniqueValueAlreadyExists) {
    // just dispatch the action to add a warning to global state
    // don't throw any error here
    dispatch(addWarning('Is the user sure they want someValue here for someProperty?'));
  }
};
```